# How to sum map values based on two keys?

Tags: groovy

I have a map with two keys (`customer` and `price`) like the one shown below:

```
[
    customer: ['Clinton', 'Clinton', 'Mark', 'Antony', 'Clinton', 'Mark'], 
    price: [15000.0, 27000.0, 28000.0, 56000.0, 21000.0, 61000.0]
]
```

`customer` and `price` values are mapped by their index positione i.e first name from `customer` list maps with the first price and so on.

Example

```
Cliton price is 15000.0
Cliton price 27000.0
Mark price 28000.0
Antony price 56000.0
Clinton price 21000.0
Mark price 61000.0
```

I would like to sum up price grouped by names. Expected output:

```
Clinton price 63000
Mark price 89000
Antony price 56000
```

Are there any built-in functions to achieve this in Groovy, or do I need to iterate over the map and sum values by writing my own functions?

Answer (score 3):

You can start with a transpose on both lists to get tuples of customer and price.  From there its basically like the other answers (group by customer, build map with customer and summed up prices).  E.g.:

```
def data = [
    customer:['Clinton', 'Clinton', 'Mark', 'Antony', 'Clinton', 'Mark'], 
    price:[15000.0, 27000.0, 28000.0, 56000.0, 21000.0, 61000.0]
]

println(
    [data.customer, data.price].transpose().groupBy{ c, p -> c }.collectEntries{ c, ps -> [c, ps*.last().sum() ] }
)
// => [Clinton:63000.0, Mark:89000.0, Antony:56000.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the problems like this, we should always plan having every entry as separate object inside a list to make it intuitive and future easy manipulation in the list.

In that case the same result can be obtained in naturally

```
def list = [

        [customer: 'Clinton', price: 15000.0],
        [customer: 'Clinton', price: 27000.0],
        [customer: 'Mark',    price: 28000.0],
        [customer: 'Antony',  price: 56000.0],
        [customer: 'Clinton', price: 21000.0],
        [customer: 'Mark',    price: 61000.0]
]


def map = list.groupBy({it.customer}).collectEntries {k, v -> [k, v.price.sum()]}

map.each {println it}
```

Comment: I guess OP's problem comes from the fact that he receives a map in given format. Your answer would be better if you present the way to transform input format to the one you have presented.

Comment: Ok. That is a point. In that case, it becomes same as @cfrick's solution

Answer (score 0):

The followint creates a map of `price` aggregated by `customer`:

```
def vals = (0..(-1+map.customer.size()))
           .collect{['name':map.customer[it], 'price': map.price[it]]}
           .groupBy{it['name']}
           .collectEntries{[(it.key): it.value.collect{it['price']}.sum()]}
```

That results in:

```
[Clinton:63000.0, Mark:89000.0, Antony:56000.0]
```

It's essentially an iteration using a range of numbers from `0` to `map.customer.size() - 1`, followed by a group-by with sum of values.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting below values for this [Clinton:15000.0, Clinton:27000.0, Mark:28000.0, Antony:56000.0, Clinton:21000.0, Mark:61000.0]

Answer (score 0):

This version is derived from @cfrick's answer, with an alternative to the summation. Using a map with default values isn't as "functional"/declarative, but IMHO the code is arguably easier to grok later (i.e. maintenance):

Given:

```
def map = [
    customer: ['Clinton', 'Clinton', 'Mark', 'Antony', 'Clinton', 'Mark'],
    price: [15000.0, 27000.0, 28000.0, 56000.0, 21000.0, 61000.0]
]
```

Approach:

```
def getSumMap = { data ->
    def result = [:].withDefault { c -> 0.0 }

    [data.customer, data.price].transpose().each { c, p -> result[c] += p }

    result
}

assert 63000.0 == getSumMap(map)['Clinton']
assert 89000.0 == getSumMap(map)['Mark']
assert 56000.0 == getSumMap(map)['Antony']
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting below error Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.math.BigDecimal.plus() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild) values: [15000.0]
Possible solutions: plus(), plus(java.math.MathContext), plus(java.lang.Character), plus(java.lang.Number), plus(java.lang.String), ulp() 
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.math.BigDecimal.plus() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild) values: [15000.0]

Comment: The answer works for me with Groovy 2.4.9. I have posted it here - https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_groovy/tree/master/egg_37_stack_overflow_51903562 ... What version of Groovy and Java are you using?